# Get current month using suger.js Java-Script

Tags: javascript, date

```
<!-- Date Range - Script  -->
<script>
$(function()
{

    // Set the default dates
    var startDate   = Date.create().addDays(-6),    // 7 days ago
        endDate     = Date.create();                // today

    var range = $('.range');

    // Show the dates in the range input
    range.val(startDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}') + ' - ' + endDate.format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}'));

    range.daterangepicker
    ({
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: endDate,
        ranges:
        {
            'This Month': [Date.create().addMonths(-1), 'today']
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I am using a `sugar.min.js`. I want to get the current month which starts from date 1 to current date.

This `This Month': [Date.create().addMonths(-1), 'today']` will give me the date from 04/**04**/2014 to 05/**04**/2014. I don't want the previous month date, instead i want this
**05/01**/2014 to 05/**04**/2014

Comment: I've never used Sugar, but can you create a Date then set its day component to 1?

Comment: @James using Sugar or without sugar.js?

Comment: actually i only want this using sugar js.

Comment: With sugar. Just reading to docs, it looks like you can do Date.create() .beginningOfMonth().

Comment: @James where you read this doc? this solved my problem. please submit your answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options from sugar's [manipulating dates](http://sugarjs.com/dates#manipulating_dates) documentation:

```
Date.create().set({day: 1})
Date.create().beginningOfMonth()
```